# Send Outlook Calendar Invite as email nor ical using PHP

Tags: php, events, vba, outlook, calendar

I am in a situation where i would need recipients with Outlook/or Equivalent(blackberry etc) to receive calendar events in Outlook Calendar event format, not an ical attachement.

This is to enable me use outlook calendar specific headers (Anyone knows what these header commands are?) like cancel, modify etc. 
I figured that i am just missing the correct MIME header string which Outlook needs to interpret the email as an Outlook calendar.

I would really appreciate any help on this. All my clients use Outlook based mail softwares (over a 1000 of them).

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to broadcast an event or sync calendars between your recipients?  Do you have one parent with many children?

Comment: Yes, i want to broadcast event changes to multiple clients.All clients use outlook so they would like to receive the events as outlook calendar events so they easily manage them.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I didn't get back to you.  This may not be the exact solution that you were looking for, but it could work.

Here's a howto that shows to send a [calendar request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655909%28v=office.12%29.aspx).  It looks like the content type "`text/calendar`" and the header shold be "`content-disposition`", "`attachment; filename=<file>`"

You could generate an ICS and send that out via email or downloadable link on your site.  Here's an example of an ICS file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Pacific Time (US & Canada)
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20061105T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20070311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:Daylight Savings Time
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID="Pacific Time (US & Canada)":20110405T120000
DTEND;TZID="Pacific Time (US & Canada)":20110405T130000
LOCATION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Location of the event
UID:100000000034201184
DTSTAMP:20110328T124055Z
DESCRIPTION:1. Click this link to join the Webinar:\n\n   https://www2.gotomeeting.com/join/000000000/000000000\n\n\n2. Choose one of the following audio options:\n\n   TO USE YOUR COMPUTER'S AUDIO:\n   When the Webinar begins, you will be connected to audio using your computer's microphone and speakers (VoIP). A headset is recommended.\n\n\n
SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Subject of the event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. This was the method i used previously but outlook does not automatically detect the email as a calendar invite. The email only shows an ical calendar attachment then you have to download and manually add it to your calendar. Normally, you can send an outlook calendar event to another user(outlook) and it automatically gets added to the user's outlook calendar.

Comment: what if you made it: application/octet-stream AND Content-Disposition: inline; filename= ?

Comment: So, i just get a random binary file attached to it

Comment: Bummer, I'll try more tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking through the source of a calendar invitation I received and I noticed this header

```
Content-Class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage
```

I'm using Apple Mail but I wonder if there is some consistency accross email clients with the use of "calendarmessage". Just thought is was worth mentioning.